# Extract a value from a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file with many lines, one is:

```
COMPOSER_HOME=/home/glen/.composer
```

I want to extract the string `/home/glen/.composer` from this file in my shell script. How can I?

I can get the whole line with `grep` but not sure how to remove the first part.

Comment: If the other lines in your file are also structured like this: `source your_file; echo "$COMPOSER_HOME"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
grep 'COMPOSER_HOME=' file| cut -d= -f2
```

`cut` cut's by delimiter `=` and the 2nd portion would be whatever is After the `=` e.g.: `/home/glen/.composer` , with `-f1` you would get `COMPOSER_HOME`

Comment: This works but apparently the numbering starts at 1, so `-f2` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), you have GNU grep which includes PCRE

```sh
grep -oP 'COMPOSER_HOME=\K.+' file
```

The `\K` means match what comes before, then throw it out and operate on the rest of the line.

You can also use awk

```sh
awk -F "=" '$1 == "COMPOSER_HOME" {print $2}' file
```

Comment: I like your `grep`-only solution!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is enough

```sh
sed -nE 's/COMPOSER_HOME=(.*)/\1/p' your_file
```

It does not print any line unless you explicitly request it (`-n`), it matches the line starting with `COMPOSER_HOME=` and captures what follows `(.*)` (using `()` instead of `\(\)`, thanks to `-E`), and puts in the replacement only what is captured. Then requests the printing of the line with the `p` flag of the `s`ubstitution command.